# Magento2: How to add custom attribute value in Email template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

I want add custom attribute value in new order email template.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

If the name of the attribute is the following:

```
your_attribute
```

Just modify the following template:

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

with copying to:

```
/app/design/frontend/XXXX/YYYY/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

and insert the following statement to show the variable in the email:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getData('your_attribute')); ?>
```

tested with M2.3.4

Comment: This way I print the option's ID, how do I print the textual value instead?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static string you can do this in your transactional email template

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/variables-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

You can the value of custom attribute in the order email using the following code:

> {{trans "%custom_attribute"
>   custom_attribute=$order.getCustomAttribute()}}